# fire different execution on window resize event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel, window-resize

I have the following carousel code **[[fiddle]](http://jsfiddle.net/stonecold111/YrPc7/3/)** that returns a different number of items to display based on screen size.

```
$(function() {

var mini = 1000;
var big = 1280;
     if (window.screen.availWidth < mini) {
$('#carousel1').jsCarousel({ onthumbnailclick: function(src) { load(src); }, autoscroll: true, circular: true, masked: false, itemstodisplay: 3, orientation: 'h' });
}
else {

$('#carousel1').jsCarousel({ onthumbnailclick: function(src) { load(src); }, autoscroll: true, circular: true, masked: false, itemstodisplay: 5, orientation: 'h' });    
    }
});
```

I want to add a `.resize` function to it so the number of items will also change on window resize. I followed this **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/BaNRq/1/)** but couldn't get it to work. Would anyone please tell me how to add the resize function to my example?

My failed attempt **([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stonecold111/YrPc7/2/))**:

```
function screen_resize() {
 var h = parseInt(window.innerHeight);
    var w = parseInt(window.innerWidth);

if (w <= 800) {
$('#carousel1').jsCarousel({ onthumbnailclick: function(src) { load(src); }, autoscroll: true, circular: true, masked: false, itemstodisplay: 3, orientation: 'h' });
    }
else {

$('#carousel1').jsCarousel({ onthumbnailclick: function(src) { load(src); }, autoscroll: true, circular: true, masked: false, itemstodisplay: 5, orientation: 'h' });   

}
}
// if window resize call responsive function
$(window).resize(function(e) {
    screen_resize();
});
// call responsive function on default :)
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    screen_resize();
    });
```

Comment: You are redefining jsCarousel on '#carousel1' element on each resize. You should initialize plugin only once on DOM ready and then just update the option `itemstodisplay` on each resize instead. Checked quickly plugin source, it doesn't seem to support it.

Comment: Usually a good plugin has destroy and re-init methods, but I am not sure about the one you are using. That way, on window resize, you can unbind the plugin via destroy and reinitiate via re-init with the desired number of items. So, you may want to look for another plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this:

```
window.onresize = screen_resize;
```

Edit: Your carousel looks good if you call screen_resize once, but breaks if you call it more than once. `screen_resize` is called in your code though and works as programmed.

Comment: Thank you. I checked your fiddle but it didn't seem to change the execution on window resize.